# How do I execute a mutable function after immutable?

Tags: rust

I'm creating a virtual machine and I'm trying to take two items from the stack. It does it in this order:

```
PEEK (Get value),
TAKE (Erase from stack),
PEEK (Get value beneath previous value)
```

However I'm running into an error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.plate` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
   --> src/machine/mod.rs:398:17
    |
397 |                 let apple = self.plate.peek();
    |                             ----------------- immutable borrow occurs here
398 |                 self.plate.take();
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
401 |                     int: apple.value.int,
    |                          --------------- immutable borrow later used here
```

Been looking for fixes... However, I couldn't find a way to work around this problem. Here's my code:

(machine/mod.rs):

```
MERGE => {
    let apple = self.plate.peek();
    self.plate.take();
    let banana = self.plate.peek();
    let seasoning = GetValueOfType {
        int: apple.value.int,
        float: 0.0,
        str: banana.value.str.clone(),
    };

    let edible = PackedIngredients {
        istype: SupportedTypes::Int,
        value: seasoning,
    };
}
```

(plate/mod.rs)

```
// This function is really internal since it has no use in instructions.
pub fn peek(&self) -> &Food { return self.area.last().unwrap(); }
```

```
// Taken't?
pub fn take(&mut self) {
    if self.area.len() == 0 {
        panic!("\u{001b}[31mUser attempted to take from an empty plate.\u{001b}[0m")
    }
    self.area.pop();
    return; // Swapped to prevent E0308.
}
```

*(Plate is just the stack)*

Tried making the `peek` function `&mut self`, but that creates more problems since you can only have one mutable in given area.

Studying various guides online, borrowing, immuts, muts, but couldn't find anything that fits / solves my problem.

Comment: `let apple = self.plate.peek(); self.plate.take();` Peeking will return a reference to the last value, but then you try to pop the last value from the end. This would invalidate the reference. Maybe you should change `take` to return the value removed?

Comment: @PitaJ Tried your suggestion but it unfortunately didn't work. It does work when I get value after removal but this would not return a desired result as it would return the value under removed value.

Comment: Please edit your question with exactly what you tried, and detail exactly the behavior you want and how what you got differed.

Comment: @PitaJ Many apologies. I made the `take` function return the exact same thing that `peek` returned. Here's what it returned: `return self.area.last().unwrap();`, now this works but it gets the top of the plate after the value has been removed. This left me confused on how to proceed, I tried `let last = self.area.last.unwrap()` before it popped and made it return `return last;` but it won't work and will give me the exact same result as my original problem did. I want it to get the top of stack before it removes the top of stack, the difference was that the successful example popped, got value

Comment: Just `return self.area.pop().unwrap();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making an immutable borrow here:

```
let apple = self.plate.peek();
```

This is because you're taking an immutable reference to self `&self` and returning `&Food`, the borrow checker is not that smart to figure out the `&Food` doesn't belong to `&self` and can only assume that you borrowed part of `&self`.

Then you tried to use mutate `self.plate`, the problem here is after that you used the `apple` reference `int: apple.value.int` which means that `apple` can't be dropped until that line, which results in the error.

There is 2 solutions to this problem:

```
Return the struct itself and not a reference
pub fn peek(&self) -> Food { return self.area.last().unwrap(); }
```

Or let `apple` get dropped before you call `self.plate.peek()`

```
let apple = self.plate.peek();
// since integer is a Copy then this will copy the int value
let int = apple.value.int;
// `apple` will be dropped here since it is no longer use after
self.plate.take();
let banana = self.plate.peek();
let seasoning = GetValueOfType {
    int,
    float: 0.0,
    str: banana.value.str.clone(),
};
```